# Proof: $\mathbb{R}^n $ is separable, show that every open cover of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a countable subcover

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, compactness, separable-spaces

**Using the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n $ is separable, show that every open cover of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a countable subcover.**

I was given a hint to prove the following claim and if needed, incorporate it into the original proof: ''A set is open if and only if it is equal to an arbitrary collection of open balls", which I have been able to prove both ways. However, I don't see how I can use that to go about the original proof.

Otherwise, I thought of the following statements

$(i)$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ is separable

$(ii)$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact

$(iii)$ Any open cover of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a countable subcover

It would have been great if I could have proved $(i)\Rightarrow(ii)\Rightarrow(iii)$ but the problems that arise are

1. Firstly, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not compact. Also, ''Every compact metric space is separable", which means $(ii)\Rightarrow(i)$.

2. ''For a compact space, every open cover has a **finite** subcover", which is not equivalent to countability.

How should I prove this? How are separability and claimed fact requirements to the proof?

**Edit.** The attempted second method is obviously wrong because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not compact.

Comment: Note: I have already tried to take help from these questions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948349/prove-k-is-compact-i-e-k-is-closed-and-bounded-implies-any-open-cover-for-k?rq=1 , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/718301/prove-that-x-is-compact-if-and-only-if-every-cover-of-x-by-members-of-b-ha , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3413947/every-sequence-in-x-has-a-cluster-point-in-x-implies-every-open-cover-of?rq=1

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not compact

Comment: @Caffeine right, thank you

Comment: Can you forget points with all rational coordinates?

Comment: @Brozovic I am not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Do you want a proof only using separability?

Comment: @JulianQuast I am unable to prove it with or without separability. Any proof would be great, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Cover $\Bbb R^n$ with *any* countable collection of compact sets (e.g. all closed balls of radius $\sqrt n$ centred on points with integral coordinates). Now just cover each of these sets separately with a finite subcover. A countable union of finite covers is countable.

I don't see where I've used the separability of $\Bbb R^n$, but I'm sure it's hidden somewhere in there...

Comment: Compact subsets of \Bbb R^n are separable so a countable union of compact subsets of \Bbb R^n is separable.

Comment: I think it's fair to say you haven't used the separability of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Rather what you've done is show that every $\sigma$-compact space is has the "Lindelöf property" (every open cover admits a countable subcover). Even a compact space doesn't need to be separable.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb R^n = \bigcup_{x \in \mathbb Z^n} ([0,1]^n + x)$, write $A_x = [0,1]^n + x$. The $A_x$ cover $\mathbb R^n$. Let $\mathcal U$ be a cover of $\mathbb R^n$, then $\mathcal U$ covers $A_x$ and has a finite subcover $\mathcal U_x$. The set $\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb Z^n} \mathcal U_x$ is a countable cover.

Here are generalizations, as mentioned in a comment:

1. Every hemicompact space is countably compact.
2. Every separable metric space is countably compact.

Comment: Separable metrizable spaces are 2nd-countable, and 2nd-countable spaces are Lindelof.